# Nginx http_mp4_module seam installed but dont work

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I try to use the http_mp4_module on my Ubuntu server but that didnt seem to work at all.
When i check nginx -V i get :

```
nginx version: nginx/1.1.19
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/chunkin-nginx-module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/headers-more-nginx-module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-development-kit --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-http-push --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-lua --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-upload-module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-upload-progress --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module
```

`--with-http_mp4_module` and `--with-http_flv_module` are there, I also add on sites-available/domaine.conf

```
location ~ .mp4$ {
mp4;
mp4_buffer_size 4M;
mp4_max_buffer_size 10M;
}

location ~ .flv$ {
flv;
}
```

and Nginx restarted witout error, everything seem ok but when i check my urls myvideo.mp4?start=60 return a 404 error (what i think is normal) and video.mp4?starttime=60 return the video but whatever the starttime number is i get the full video from the begining, did i miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

You should request `video.mp4?start=60`, not `video.mp4?starttime=60`.

A quote from [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html):

> The pseudo-streaming works in alliance with a compatible Flash players. A player sends an HTTP request to the server with a start time specified in the query string argument (named simply **start** and specified in seconds), and the server responds with the stream such that its start position corresponds to the requested time, for example:
>
> `http://example.com/elephants_dream.mp4?start=238.88`

p.s. Please also note, that you're using obsolete and unsupported version of nginx from development branch. Upgrade to the latest stable or mainstream is strongly advised.

Comment: Thanks you bbut as i say i get a 404 error with ?start and i dont get any with ?starttime maybe my nginx version work with the starttime request. Also i see some website using `startparam: "starttime"`in jwplayer.

Comment: The 404 error has nothing to do with query parameters. You can request `video.mp4?qwertyuiop` and still get the video.

Comment: _maybe my nginx version work with the starttime request_ All nginx versions from nginx.org don't work with `starttime`. But with 3rd party patches and modules you can experience any strange and undocumented behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure that `myvideo.mp4` exists in requested directory, and your request actually is caught by `location ~ .mp4$`? Check your configuration. I'm sure 404 doesn't related to mp4 module at all.

Comment: Just [turn on debug log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) and look what happens.

Comment: I updated my Nginx, i rename my mp4 into flv and now its working. Thank You.